# Delete item from a table if related data is missing from other tables?

Tags: mysql

Adding from multiple tables is now easy.

But I'm looking for a way to selectively Remove rows from a table based on a Lack of finds in others..

If say .. Table_Important
(ID, ImportantValue, other, stuff, nobody, cares, about)


I want to remove all rows where the **ImportantValue** does not appear in
Table_Remembering in the colum **CouldBeImportant**
nor in
Table_Forgetting in the column **WasThatImportant**

So far i've been using joins to find the instances where it Does occur, and inserting those to a temporary table, deleting the original, re-making it, and then copying the temp table into it, and deleting That.
It's slow, and certainly not the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a couple of `exists` operators:

```
DELETE 
FROM   table_important i
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table_remembering r
                   WHERE  i.important_value = r.could_be_important) AND 
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table_forgetting f
                   WHERE  i.important_value = f.was_that_important)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the actual structure is not disclosed by OP, only a generic hint:

```
DELETE FROM a WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.key FROM b where b.key = a.key) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.key FROM c where c.key = a.key)
```